# Koala batch operations in models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, koala

I have a Ruby on Rails app that allows the user to login with their Facebook account. I want to be able to a list of users and their Facebook data. I have been able to accomplish this however I have to send a request for each user's name and I want to do this as a batch operation. How would I be able to put this in my user model?

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :uid

  def facebook_name
    Koala::Facebook::API.new.get_object(uid)["name"].to_s
  end
end
```

**Example of Inefficient code**

```
users = Users.all

users.each do |user|
  puts user.facebook_name
end
```

Comment: do u want to populate username immediately??

Comment: @checkit Yes. I want to be able to show the user's facebook name based on their uid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a background task (such as https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) to populate the data in the database.

For example

```
class User
 after_create :delayed_populate

 def populate_from_facebook
   self.facebook_name = Koala::Facebook::API.new.get_object(uid)["name"].to_s
 end

 def delayed_populate
   delay.populate_from_facebook
 end 
end
```

Then, once you've done that, it's just a regular model database to iterate through them, as the fields will be cached in your DB. You really don't want to be making HTTP api requests during responding to another HTTP request.

Comment: What happens if the user changes their facebook name? How do I know the name was update?

Comment: If that's a worry for you, you set a cron task (https://github.com/javan/whenever) to kick off an update in the background however frequently you need to check. It's usually not critical to have exact up to the minute information, and even if it is, you can expose a "update" button to kick off another background task. For example, will your users know if it's updated every 5 minutes instead of instantly?